# Converting a time string to UNIX timestamp

Tags: php, datetime, date, time

How can I convert a time string like this:

> 30/7/2010

to a UNIX timestamp?

I tried `strtotime()` but I get a empty string :(

Comment: `strtotime` doesn't work because (from the doc) "The function expects to be given a string containing a US English date format"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP >= 5.3:

```
$var = DateTime::createFromFormat('j/n/Y','30/7/2010')->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 5):

You're using UK date format.

Quick and dirty method:

```
$dateValues = explode('/','30/7/2010');
$date = mktime(0,0,0,$dateValues[1],$dateValues[0],$dateValues[2]);
```

Comment: This is what I came up with too -- is there really no function that takes a date format string and a textual date string and returns the timestamp? It seems like a weird gap in PHP's date interface

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php (`strptime`) since your date is in a different format than what PHP might be expecting.

Comment: +1. If you've got PHP >= 5.1 and a date format that doesn't work with strtotime, strptime is definitely an option.

Answer (score 0):

You could also convert it to a format that strtotime() can accept, like Y/M/D:

```
$tmp = explode($date_str);
$converted = implode("/", $tmp[2], $tmp[1], $tmp[0]);
$timestamp = strtotime($converted);
```

Comment: If you're going to do that you might as well just `mktime(0, 0, 0, $tmp[1], $tmp[0], $tmp[2]);`

Answer (score 0):

The PHP 5.3 answer was great

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('j/n/Y','30/7/2010')->getTimestamp();
```

Here is a < 5.3.0 solution

```
$timestamp = getUKTimestamp('30/7/2010');

function getUKTimestamp($sDate) {
    list($day, $month, $year) = explode('/', $sDate);
    return strtotime("$month/$day/$year");
}
```