# How can we find First and last day of a date

Tags: php, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In PHP, is there an easy way to get the first and last date of a month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589/in-php-is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-the-first-and-last-date-of-a-month)

How can we find First and last day of a date?

I have a date "01/05/2011". i am getting this date dynamically. so i like to know the last day of this date. like '31 or 30 or 28 or 29'.

i want to find it using php...

Comment: Use the search function before asking: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=first+and+last+day+of+month+php

Comment: and just in case the date format gives you any trouble, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399075/php-datetimecreatefromformat-in-5-2 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348396/converting-a-time-string-to-unix-timestamp

Answer (score 4):

### This function may help you :

```
function lastday($month = '', $year = '')
    {
       if (empty($month)) {
          $month = date('m');
       }
       if (empty($year)) {
          $year = date('Y');
       }
       $result = strtotime("{$year}-{$month}-01");
       $result = strtotime('-1 second', strtotime('+1 month', $result));
       return date('Y-m-d', $result);
    }
```

---

Call like

```
$month = 3;
$year = 2011;
$lastDay = $this->lastday($month, $year);
```

That will give you the last day of the March 2011......

Answer (score 2):

```
echo date('t', strtotime('01/05/2011'));
```

should do the trick